# toggle function to limited tags on click event

Tags: jquery

I have 10 boxes, I have added toggle functions to it to select the box by adding class 'active'. I want to let user to select only 6 boxes. When user selects 6 boxes it not letting to select others which is working fine. My problem is I want to change my selection again but it is not letting me to do that. Below is code:`

```
$('a').click(function() {
     if ($('.active').length < 6) {
         $(this).toggleClass('active')
     } else {
         alert('more then 6 selection not allowed')

     }
 })
```

`I want to change my selection but it is not letting to do because if condition is true. How to un-select the selected boxes, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the hasClass to determine if the selection can be undone.

That way, if its an unselection, it is allowed.

```
$('a').click(function() {
     if ($('.active').length < 6 || $(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).toggleClass('active')
     } else {
         alert('more then 6 selection not allowed')

     }
 })
```

Comment: This worked, I was checking hasClass on all the elements instead of $(this) item. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.

[image]

You should use this condition:

```
if ($('.active').length < 6 || $(this).hasClass('active'))
```

**Run** my code:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     if ($('.active').length < 6 || $(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).toggleClass('active')
     } else {
         alert('more then 6 selection not allowed')

     }
 })
```

```css
a.active{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;">link 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 2</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 3</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 4</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 5</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 6</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 7</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 8</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 9</a>
<a href="javascript:;">link 10</a>
```

Comment: then you for your peace of code. I was doing the same thing but was missing $(this)

Answer (score 0):

You can write logic like this (remove the class `active` if it already has and return)

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        return;
    }
    if ($('.active').length < 6) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } else {
        alert('more then 6 selection not allowed');
    }
})
```