# javascript find which label.btn clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am kinda new to javascript and I checked lessons on w3 about javascript but i did not get my answer so far.

I have a question and 4 options and I want to change the color of label.btn that clicked on.

javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $("label.btn").on('click',function () {
        var choice = $(this).find('input:radio').val();

        $( "#answer" ).html(  $(this).checking(choice) );

        ClickedLabel.style.backgroundColor = "black"; // I want to change te color here
    });

///
};
```

html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="quiz" id="quiz" data-toggle="buttons">
<label id="first" class="element-animation1 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="1">1 One</label>
<label id="second" class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="2">2 Two</label>
<label id="third" class="element-animation3 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="3">3 Three</label>
<label id="fourth" class="element-animation4 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="4">4 Four</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `$(this).css({'background-color': 'black'});`

Comment: You use the button to find the input....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **A)**

**Run** my code and switch between the options.

```js
$(function(){
    $("label.btn").on('click',function () {
        $("label.btn").css('background-color','transparent'); 
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="quiz" id="quiz" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label id="first" class="element-animation1 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
          <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
          <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="1">1 One</label>
        <label id="second" class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
          <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
          <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="2">2 Two</label>
        <label id="third" class="element-animation3 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
          <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
          <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="3">3 Three</label>
        <label id="fourth" class="element-animation4 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
          <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
          <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="4">4 Four</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**OR**

In this example I used the `closest` method to find the wrapper label of the clicked radio button and used `.css('background-color','red')` to change its color. Also I wrote `$("label.btn").css('background-color','transparent');`  to reset the color of all options to `transparent` in each click first.

```js
$(function(){
    $("input").on('click',function () {
          $("label.btn").css('background-color','transparent'); 
          $(this).closest("label").css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="quiz" id="quiz" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="first" class="element-animation1 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
      <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
      <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="1">1 One</label>
    <label id="second" class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
      <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
      <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="2">2 Two</label>
    <label id="third" class="element-animation3 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
      <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
      <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="3">3 Three</label>
    <label id="fourth" class="element-animation4 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
      <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
      <input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="4">4 Four</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### **B)**

Another way is to **`toggle` a `active` class** on the clicked item. I have been written an example based on this way **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475409/toggle-function-to-limited-tags-on-click-event/48475466#48475466)**. Toggle a class is a nice way ;)

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` will be the label that was clicked.  You can use jquery to change the background color through `.css`

Instead of

```
ClickedLabel.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

you can use

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'black');
```

If you would rather use `style.backgroundColor` you can get the base element and modify that:

```
$(this)[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).css("background-color","black");
```

Comment: So, would you like to say something about it ?